# going through directories in bash within for loops

Tags: bash, loops, variables, directory

I have a directory like this figure: [image]

I have written a bash script that first goes to steady subdirectory, reads each folder inside it and performs tasks. Then it goes to transient subdirectory, loops over folders there and needs to map results through an openFOAM command that requires similar subfolder from other subdirectory (like mapping from steady/1 to transient/1). Both steady and transient folders are under same parent directory.
Basically, I want to find a way in the second for-loop to map from
"scale/steady/1" to "scale/transient/1" and the same for other subfolder (i.e. 2).
I know that I have to replace "1" in the second for loop with a varible .
Would some body assist me how I can do so?

```
for d in steady/*/
do
     echo "$d"
     (cd "$d" && touch steady.log&& simpleFoam > steady.log)
done

for i in transient/*/
do
     echo "$i"
     (cd $i && touch transient.log && mapFields ../../steady/1 -consistent)
done
```

Comment: `... && mapFields ../../steady/"${i#transient/}" -consistent)` (see what `${parameter#}` mean: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Answer (score 0):

```
for steady_folder in steady/*
do
     transient_folder="${steady_folder/steady/transient}"
     echo "$steady_folder"
     .....
     echo "$transient_folder"
     .....
done
```